# Docker hub documentation to connect to postgresql container

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker and I'm looking to connect Ruby app(container) to use pg database(postgres container).

but before that, I'm unable to connect Postgres using the [docker hub documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)

```
docker run --name pg1 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword POSTGRES_USER=seceretuser postgres
```

```
docker run -it --rm postgres psql -h pg1 -U seceretuser
```

But I'm getting the following error.

```
psql: error: could not translate host name "pg1" to address: Name or service not known
```

My understanding for not providing a network (as mention in docker hub documentation) is if no network is provided the docker use the default bridge network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, very specifically the one thing containers can't do on the default bridge network is to resolve each other by name: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

> Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the `--link` option, which is considered legacy. **On a user-defined bridge network**, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.

The problem you are facing is that while your containers can talk to each other by IP, your second `psql` container can't find the hostname `pg1` and convert it to an IP.

You can follow instructions in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) to create a user-defined bridge network and run both containers attached to it.

*Hint: You might find it easier to work with `docker-compose` for this type of task.  It let's you create the network and attach containers to it a little more easily in code rather than on the command line.*